# What is wrong with my pear trees

Tags: pear

I just planted two pear trees and two apple trees this year. At first, all four started putting on leaves and looked healthy. Now, the apple trees are thriving and the leaves on the pear tress are dying. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: If you post a picture, we will be able to figure it out for ya.

Comment: What do the leaves that are dying look like? Do they turn black, yellow or just shrivel up? Do they have spots?

Comment: Watering is critical to young trees as they establish new roots. Planting depth also matters a lot.